# Access iframe functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This problem seem to happen only in chrome
This is the iframe code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function blahblah() { alert("test"); }
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p> lalalalallalala!!! </p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is how I create the iframe

```
<iframe src="iframetest.html" id="iframetest"></iframe>
```

I then try to call the iframe's blahblah() function:

```
$('#iframetest')[0].contentWindow.blahblah()
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried just `$('#iframetest').contentWindow.blahblah()`? (Note, the lack of `[0]`)

Comment: When did you call the function? Are you sure that the iframe is already loaded at this time?

Comment: It's loaded as I can see it through chrome's console
I did try without [0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works :

```
  <iframe id=iframetest src=iframetest.html></iframe>
  <script>
      $(window).load(function(){
         document.getElementById('iframetest').contentWindow.blahblah();
      });
  </script>
```

Note that I used `$(window).load` to ensure the iframe was loaded. Using [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on `document` wouldn't ensure the iframe is loaded.

Of course, your iframe must have the same origin as the parent document (which also means you must open your file in `http://` in your browser and not `file://`).

EDIT : [Working demo](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/)

Comment: I tested it on Chrome. Are you sure you used $(window).load ? Are both html files of the same origin ?

Comment: both files are runnning on localhost. 
Also I'm sure the content is loaded as I do it from chorme's console

Comment: I have marked you as the accepted answer because you are right, but still it doesn't work for me. maybe the localhost has something to do withit?

Comment: localhost is fine (I tested as localhost). Try to spot the differences with my document. Hard to say something else (I'll be back if I've an idea).