# Bind load-event to iframe or run function if the load-event already fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, event-handling

Say I want to bind a load-event to an iframe:

```
var callback = function() {
    //Loaded
};
$('iframe').one('load', callback);
```

That works well enough, except I can not be sure that the iframe is not already loaded. In that case, the load-event has already fired and my function will never run.

How do I check if the iframe already is loaded?

```
var callback = function() {
    //Loaded
};
if(iframe already loaded) {
    callback();
} else {
    $('iframe').one('load', callback);
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361465/how-to-check-if-click-event-is-already-bound-jquery

Comment: @lmgonzalves: Thanks, but not quite what I am looking for. I do not want to check for other event-handlers. I want to make sure that the function is run even if I am to late to catch the load event.

Comment: You could check for a method or varibale to be defined in the source of an iframe like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173793/access-iframe-functions). If it exists iframe is loaded.

Comment: @LarsEbert See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766086/detect-when-an-iframe-is-loaded/

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36155560/3894981

Answer (score 1):

You can check `readyState`:

```
var iframe = $('iframe');
if (iframe.prop('contentWindow') && iframe.prop('contentWindow').document.readyState === 'complete') {
    callback();
} else {
    iframe.one('load', callback);
}
```

Comment: in chrome readystate will be "completed", but using `$iframe.contents().find("*")` will return an empty `body` element.