# Calling Child iFrame JS function from Parent window cross-domain

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, cross-domain, parent

**Here is my scenario:**
I have a parent window MyParent.php which embeds an iFrame(id=Myiframe) and loading a site "ChildSite" which is obviously a different domain. This childsite is not under my control. It has few JS functions, for example myChildFunction(str).

Is it possible for the parent window to access the JS functions of the child iframe? Most of the recommendations are about using ***postMessage*** but with that we can only access the data but not access the function. Is there any other way?

Any help is very much appreciated! I'm cracking my head for past few days on this.

```html
MyParent.php

<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: text/html");
?>

<html>
<iframe id=Myiframe width=50%></iframe>
</iframe>

<script>
var Myiframe=document.getElementById('Myiframe');
Myiframe.src='https://childsite.com';
Myiframe.onload=function() { 
alert('iframe loaded');

var frameDocument = Myiframe.contentDocument ? Myiframe.contentDocument : Myiframe.contentWindow.document;
document.getElementById('Myiframe').contentWindow.myChildFunction(abc);

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this will solve your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173793/access-iframe-functions

Comment: Thanks Puk, for looking in. I had gone through this link earlier itself. That recommendation works for SAME-ORIGIN. My case is related to Cross Origin